# AWS ecs task definition variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

Is it possible to dynamically set values in AWS ECS task definitions?  For example.  I have the following volume definition.

```
"volumes": [
    {
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "/tmp/logs/registrations"
        },
        "name": "logs"
    }
],
```

I would like do do something like `/tmp/logs/<container_id>`.

I am trying to do this because I have multiple containers running the same app.  I need to mount each containers log directory for a sumologic collector.  The problem is if the directories aren't namespaced by container then the mounts will conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudwatch logs is another option if saving to the file system is not a requirement.

If you are using the ECS optimized AMI it's already configured and all you need to do is turn it on in the container task definition:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html

You would also need to configure log groups or log streams for each container.

Comment: This moved me in the right direction.  I ended up using the standard json logs provided by docker.  Everything is grouped by container id.

Answer (score 1):

Is saving logs to the file system a hard requirement? If not, Sumo Logic has a pretty good article about another option: [Update On Logging With Docker](https://www.sumologic.com/blog-using-sumo/update-on-logging-with-docker/).

You run the [Sumo Logic Collector for Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/sumologic/collector/) in one container and your application in another. You configure Docker to send logs from your application container to the Sumo Logic collector. This is [built into Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/), so your application shouldn't need to change. The collector container will then send those logs to Sumo Logic.

I've seen this pattern called the [sidecar](https://www.loggly.com/blog/how-to-implement-logging-in-docker-with-a-sidecar-approach/), in case you're looking for other examples of it.